How to extract all frames of a video using GTX 550 ti?
My GPU is Nvidia GTX 550 ti and I should extract all frames of video files for my job.
my GPU not support latest version of CUDA.
I tried multiple softwares to use my GPU for frame extracting but all of them use my CPU.
is there any software or way to extract all frames of a video using my GPU card?
please full explain your solution for my problem (what version must install and ...)
note that I have not enough budget for buy new GPU card

NVIDIA GPU accelerated video decoding normally uses Nvidia NVDEC, and not CUDA. The GTX 550 doesn't have the NVDEC hardware. Maybe your GPU include Nvidia PureVideo hardware. There in not much information about using "PureVideo" decoder with FFmpeg. In Windows you may try using dxva2 (DirectX) hardware decoder as described here. Maybe it uses the the "PureVideo" decoder (I am not sure).

This question is similar to: How to extract frames using ffmpeg?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

No need to complicate things trying to use hardware accelerated extraction, unless you need to do this in large volumes.
You can use ffmpeg to extract frames from a video:
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 %0d.png

You can also create JPEG or BMP, of course.
